# updating MULTI-MODEL fails by controller/where are bugs?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

following code in controller seems to have bugs, which avoid features like this

2. Condition won't be entered
3. No updating possible. Records won't be updated

var_dump of both models seems to be okay. Attributes are constitued as expected. Any ideas,what I did wrong?

Here is code of controller

```html
    public function actionUpdate($id) {
        try {
            $model = new Bewerber();
            $behavior = new \common\wsl_components\Wsl_Blameable_Behavior();
            $aktualisiert_von = $behavior->get_User_Person_Id();
            if (Yii::$app->request->post('_asnew') != '1') {
                $model = $this->findModel($id);
            }
            $model_person = Person::findOne($model->id_person);
            if (!$model || !$model_person) {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException("The user has no profile.");
            }
            $model->aktualisiert_von = $aktualisiert_von;
            $model_person->aktualisiert_von = $aktualisiert_von;
            $model->scenario = 'update';
            $model_person->scenario = 'update';
            if (Model::loadMultiple([$model, $model_person], Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                $isValid = $model->validate();
                var_dump($model->getErrors());
                $isValid = $model_person->validate() && $isValid;
                if ($isValid) {
                    $model->saveAll(false);
                    $model_person->saveAll(false);
                }
                $model->avatar = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'avatar');
                if ($model->upload()) {
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                }
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('update', [
                            'model' => $model,
                            'model_person'
                ]);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $error) { //fange den schweren MySQL-Fehler ab
            $go_back = "bewerber";
            \common\wsl_components\error_handling::error($error, $go_back);
        }
    }
```

Condition:

```
 if (Model::loadMultiple([$model, $model_person], Yii::$app->request->post()))
```

will be false. Any ideas, why?

Comment: check validation error by `$model->getErrors();`

Comment: Won't help(see above)

Comment: `loadmutiple()` doesn't makes sense here, [Read Document](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#loadMultiple()-detail). **loadMultple() says all models should have the same class.** You were using two different class.

Comment: Okay.Thx. My probelm isn't solved. I will open a new thread without this method